# Is there any characterization and/or classification of subsemigroups of finite monogenic semigroups?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids

A semigroup $S$ is called *monogenic* if $S$ is generated by some element $a$ (which is unique if $S$ is not a group) in the sense that $S=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Observe that each mongenic group is finite cyclic. 
It is known that each subsemigroup of a monogenic group is a cyclic group.

On the other hand, a subsemigroup of a finite monogenic semigroup need not be monogenic. The simplest example is the subsemigroup $\{a^2,a^3,a^4=a^5\}$ of the monogenic semigroup $\{a,a^2,a^3,a^4=a^5\}$.

Let us call a semigroup $S$ *submonogenic* if it is isomorphic to a subsemigroup of a monogenic semigroup.

**Question 1.** *Is there any reasonable characterization of (finite) submonogenic semigroups?*

It is clear that each finite submonogenic semigroup $S$ has the following properties:

(1) $S$ is commutative;

(2) $S$ has a unique idempotent;

(3) the minimal ideal $I$ of $S$ is a monogenic group;

(4) for any $a,x,y\in S$ the equality $ax=ay\notin I$ implies $x=y$;

(5) for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x,y\in S$ the equality $x^n=y^n\notin I$ implies $x=y$.

**Question 2.** *Is each finite semigroup $S$ satisfying the conditions (1)--(3) submonogenic?*

**Question 2'** (added after appearing Mark Sapir's Counterexample to Question 2). *Is each finite semigroup $S$ satisfying the conditions (1)--(5) submonogenic?*

**Question 3.** *Is any reasonable classification of finite submonogenic semigroups?*

Comment: Rings and tails.  The super (finite) semigroup has unique numbers m and p which are the least m and p such that a^m = a^m+p.  The tail has length m-1, and the ring has p elements.  If the subsemigroup is not also monogenic, then there are more elements in the tail (so it looks like the start of a numerical semigroup), and/or not many elements of the ring are needed to finish off generating the sub.  Gerhard "Yet Another Meaning Of Ring" Paseman, 2018.01.21.

Answer (score 3):

Q2: No, consider the semigroup consisting of five elements $\{a,b,c,d,0\}$ where $ab=ba=ac=ca=bc=cb=d$, all other products are 0. It is obviously a semigroup (the product of any three elements is $0$) and satisfies your conditions (1),(2),(3). Suppose it is inside a monogenic semigroup $M=\langle x\rangle$. Then $a=x^p, b=x^q, c=x^r$ for some $p<q<r$. Therefore $d$ belongs to the "ring" (see the above comment by Gerhard Paseman). Since the "ring" is a subgroup and contains 0, $d0=0d=0=0*0$, we have that $d=0$, a contradiction.

Q1=Q3. I do not think anybody worked on that. I know that the lattice of subsemigroups of a monogenic semigroup can be quite complicated (Repnitsky).

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. But at least some conjecture concerning Q1?

Comment: The Rees factor over the minimal ideal should be a subsemigroup of a monogenic nil-semigroup which probably could be described in some way.  So I would first decide if adding that condition is enough (maybe not).

Comment: You can read Grillet's book "Commutative Semigroups".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to find that book of Grillet and read. At the moment I added two new cancellativity conditions (4),(5) and modified the Question 2. Do you have some (simple) counterexample to Question 2'?

Comment: The question is unmotivated. But take the monogenic semigroup $S_n=\langle x\mid x^n=x^{n+1}\rangle$. It is a nil-semigroup. Take the 0-direct product  $T_n$ of $S_n$ with itself (the Rees factor of the direct product over the ideal consisting of pairs where one coordinate is 0). $T_n$ satisfies all your conditions.  I suspect that if $n=100$ then $T_n$ is not inside a monogenic semigroup.

Comment: Thank you for you next (hypothetical) counterexample. But why do you think that the question is unmotivated? Question 2' was motivated by Question 2 and your counterexample. In Question 2' I just wanted to formulate some natural conjecture (of course it can be wrong, but just as a second approximation). The initial question about submonogenic semigroups was motivated by the study of superextensions of semigroups. For monogenic semigroups the superextension has some nice properties, inherited by subsemigroups. So, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: It is unmotivated because your condition is already more complicated than "subsemigroups of monogenic semigroups". If you really want to know about these semigroups, read papers by Repntskii (and Kacman), ay,  MR0981521. I strongly believe that if you cannot prove or disprove that $T_n$ is inside $S_k$, there is no hope you will ever formulate a natural conjecture.

Comment: Ok, I will try (to prove or disprove) that $T_n$ embeds into some $S_k$. Thanks.